# Creating a storage account within an Azure WorkerRole

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-worker-roles

is it possible to create a new storage account for an azure account in a worker role? Maybe with cmdlets?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is certainly possible to do so. You can either install Windows Azure PowerShell Cmdlets and invoking New-AzureStorageAccount Cmdlet (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152813.aspx) or by writing a wrapper around Create Storage Account Service Management API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh264518.aspx).